# What do those evaluating fellowship candidates look for before accepting them to join their research group/department?

Tags: application, evaluation-criteria

I'm applying for a new fellowship, and I'm wondering what senior lecturers and/or professors of a research group/department look into, for evaluating the fellowship candidates, before accepting them to join their research group/department?

Comment: Sadly, one of the more common reasons I have seen lately is that a lab wants to jump on the bandwagon of a current research trend (i.e., "Big Data" currently in CS) when the current members of the lab are actually not at all interested or knowledgeable about this new trend.

Comment: @xLeitix Yes, this is unfortunate at many levels.

Comment: @xLeitix I think it is legitimate for a professor to take someone that has expertise in a research direction they want to expand in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say several points related to the candidates such as

- How much in average do candidates publish per year?
- Where do they publish?
- What conferences they presented their papers in?
- What are the impact factors for journals they publish in?
- What new research questions or directions do they have?
- How much citations did they received?
- With whom in the group they can collaborate?
- What funds do they have or can bring?
- What experience in writing proposals do they have?
- What are some similar proposals that received funds?
- Where their research is going in the next 5-10 years?
- What industry or academic experience do they have?
- What skills do they have?
- Can they enhance research group diversity?
- Can they teach, present and discuss well?

Comment: I *think* this answers a completely different question (how do you evaluate a research group).

Comment: By they I meant candidates and not the group. So what advantages can the candidates bring to a research group, will be answer to at least some of these questions.

Comment: Good list. I think you could add: 'Does the candidate know a technique that could be useful to answer the issues encountered in the lab' (examples: a type of computational model or a specific microscopy technique, etc.)